# jquery .animate opacity and background color at same time on the same element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity, background-color

I am trying to animate the opacity and the background color of an element at the same time. I am using the code below but currently only the opacity animates.

```
$("div.offer").mouseover(function() {
var myClass = $(this).attr("class");

$(this).stop().animate({width:'259px'}, {queue:false, duration:600, easing:'easeOutQuint'});

if (myClass == "offer windows") {
    $(".offer.windows .offerBackground").stop().animate({opacity:'1'}, {queue:false, duration:600, easing:'easeOutQuint'});
    $(".offer.windows .offerBackground").stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#B0C1C8'}, {queue:false, duration:600, easing:'linear'});
}
});
```

Is is possible to animate both at the same time?

Comment: You need jQueryUI to animate colors :?.. or you could do it all crazy easy with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For animating colors you need to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com). jQuery core by itself doesn't animate color-related properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made a mistake in my original description. Currently the backgroundColor animates but the opacity does not. However, if I place the 'animate opacity' command below the 'animate backgroundColor' command then the opacity animates. Is there a way to get them both animating?